# Context Path not found after migrating to Springboot 3 and Spring 6

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, contextroot

The following piece worked fine until its migration to Springboot 3.2.0 and Spring6. Ever since migration getting a 404 error i.e context root not found, on calling `/health`. The app is configured to run on an external server. Any insight would be much appreciated.

```
@RestController
public class DemoController  {

@Description("Returns app status")
    @GetMapping(value = "/health")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getAppHealth() {
       return ResponseEntity.ok("I'm up");
    }
 }
 
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "demo.com")
public class SpringbootApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringbootApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOG.debug("===============main() called==============");
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: For starters your configure method looks wrong, it doesn't setup anything. Next thing is if you are upgrading to Spring Boot 3.x from Spring Boot 2.x you will also need to upgrade your external server to a JakartaEE container. So if you are using Tomcat9 you need to upgrade to Tomcat10 else it won't work.

Comment: do you use this config in your config file : server.servlet.context-path ?

Comment: no, just this simple configuration worked fine until migration happened

Comment: @M.Deinum i removed the configure method to avoid confusion as it wasn't really doing anything. Secondly, i have migrated the external server too. Anything else which i might have missed?

Comment: Are you missing RequestMaping on controller?

Comment: No, i have used @GetMapping.

Comment: If you removed it and are deploying your application is doing exactly what it should, nothing. That method (a proper one) is needed to bootstrap it as a war. So unless you mean something else with an external server! Also generally when structured correctly you don't need the `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "demo.com")` at all.